# How to find "Time" from "Force vs. Velocity" graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, time, velocity

If I have Velocity on the $y$ axis and force on the $x$ axis how can I calculate the total time it takes to reach 4000 newtons? Is this just a case of integrating the gradient of the line?

[image]

Comment: Could you give some context?

Comment: Say a car has an automatic breaking system based on a linear actuator. The speed of operation the linear actuator decreases as the force is increased.The force needed to fully depress the break is 2000 newtons. I am trying to calculate the time needed to go from 0 newtons to 4000 newtons.

Comment: I think some detail like the travel length of your actuator is necessary.

Comment: Yes, I do apologise, the travel length is 7.5cm.

Comment: Actually we need the function of acceleration with distance or speed. We need to know how the force affects the motion to solve it.

Comment: If we just assumed F= m v' then the velocity would never change as the initial force is zero...

Answer (score 0):

If you have acceleration as a function of speed use the first equation. If you have speed as a function of position use the second equation.

$$t(v)=\int_{v_1}^{v}\frac{1}{a(v)} \, \mathrm{d}v$$
$$t(x) = \int^x_{x_1}\frac{1}{v(x)}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

It seems you have acceleration (force) as a function of speed with $a(v) = C_0 + C_1 v$. The first integral then gives

$$t(v) = \int \limits_{v_1}^{v} \frac{1}{C_0+C_1 v}\,{\rm d}v = \frac{1}{C_1} \ln \left( \frac{C_0+C_1 v}{C_0+C_1 v_1} \right ) $$

which is the equation of time between speeds of $v_1$ and $v$.